# Deployment of a Django app on Apache2 404 not found

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2

I googled it and i searched everywhere including, but i could't find any solution for my problem.

I'm trying to deploy an django application on a VPS server.

I set up apache2 with my project but when i try to go to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx i always get a 404 not found.

Here are my configurations:

**project path :** /var/www/master

**WSGI file path** /var/www/master/projectx249/wsgi.py

**Apache2 site conf path:** /etc/apache2/site-available/mekhoukh.conf

**Apache2 site conf file:** for this part this is the last conf i tried on it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

<Directory /var/www/master/projext249>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess mekhoukh python-home=/usr/lib/python3.5 python-path=/var/www/master
WSGIProcessGroup mekhoukh
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/master/projext249/wsgi.py
```

i'm using ssh to connect trough the server, i also updated the **/etc/hosts** with the public ip pointig to the domain name and the localhost ip pointing to it too.

**EDIT:**

Here's my **wsgi.py** config file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


sys.path.append('/var/www/master/projetx249/')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projetx249.settings")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: Did you try http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS/master/projext249 or http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS/master ?

Comment: Yeah i tried it's actually a typo on the apache virtual conf... messed up with it a day.